# Animate instances rotating individually in Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to animate a series of tiles arranged on a grid that would flip over and show the bottom side. I want them to rotate in sequence but I can't get that to work. No matter what I do, the tiles flip over all at the same time or in chunks of 4 or more.

I'm trying to animate the tiles based on the position of a cube. What can I do to get the tiles to flip over sequentially from one of the corners of the grid towards the opposite corner while staying flipped? Please help!

Here is the geometry nodes setup:
[image]

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: As you keep Y position of the nearest, this Y is the same for most of the instances. Why are you using Y ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

[image]

You're using the Y component of the position of a point that is the nearest for each instance.

But this Y position is the position of a vertex of the moving cube. So this is the same for all instances that are in a relative given position from the cube. 4 vertices in the cube share the same Y position and 4 other one have another Y value (in total 2 Y values).

---

We don't know why you're using Y only here.

Maybe you can use the distance instead or a combination of Y with the distance.

[image]

---

If you want the cubes stay flipped, you need to use a simulation zone, as if not, the cube instance states won't be kept (as recalculated as a simple modifier all the time).

[image]

The following setup:

Multiply delta time (the time between two frames) by some speed factor.

Test the proximity (and map range it to some values: optional).

Cumulate a previous rotation (named attribute) with the new value (angle by speed).

Cap it to pi.

Store the result.

And as output, rotate the instances.

[image]

[image] (File is 4.0, but the setting above should work in 3.6)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't have a reason for using only the Y value, I'll use the X value as well. 
I did try using distance but then the tiles wouldn't stay flipped, they would flip back once the red cube crossed their position.

Comment: You mean they should stay flipped once flipped, or the opposite (come back to their original position)? If they should stay flipped, a "simulation zone" may be used for that.

Comment: I'd like them to stay flipped once flipped.

Comment: Your suggestion works and the tiles flip and stay flipped. Thank you!
I am struggling though to animate the tiles smoothly, they are not flipping when expected so I'll keep working on that.